# Android keyboard remains after sending an email Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, email, cordova

Built a Phonegap app, and emails in this app are handled using whatever email program the user chooses after clicking the email button. The email button is just a standard HTML `<a href="mailto:address">` link.

The problem is, after the user hits send on the email, when they return to the app, the Android keyboard is still there, floating. This occurs regardless of what email program is being used, but only on Android.

I have already tried doing .focus() and .blur() as suggested in other solutions, and even added a hidden text input on the page to target with the focus/ blur action because there are no input elements on the page otherwise.

Do any of you know any other techniques to make the keyboard go away after sending an email, and/or what could cause the keyboard to remain on the screen?

Thank you all in advance.